# Win Api certificate deleted from store callback

Tags: windows, winapi

I am writing a python application that uses Win API, I wan't to know if in Win Api is possible to detect when a certificate is removed from the Windows Certificate Store ?

Comment: There are API functions for adding and removing certificates, but AKAICT there are no notifications when a certificate has been added/removed.